# Aligning an image in graphical layout

Tags: android, xml, image, xml-drawable

Hi I want to know how do I align the box to the bottom of the android screen? I have already made the box as a 9patch png image and still there is some gap between the actual image and the border. Can anyone please help me? What I mean that there is an actual gap between the blue border on the graphical layout screen that controls the size of the image and the actual image. Pardon me for my English.

This is the xml code for the blue box

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/background"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:src="@drawable/background" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/topbar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:src="@drawable/top_bar" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/topbar"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="95dp"
    android:src="@drawable/icon_green" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/box"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="23dp"
    android:src="@drawable/box" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Here is the full xml. Hope you can help :)

Comment: Can you add image's link of your current layout. You had `android:layout_marginBottom="23dp"` in your last `ImageView`.

Comment: Yul i cant add image yet since i dot have enough reputation but I'll check on the margin part

Comment: So you can add an self-answer and check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't understand the question fully but try adding

```
 android:adjustViewBounds="true"
```

to your ImageViews.

And i see the view with id 'box' is aligned to the bottom and has a bottom margin of 23dp. This will create a gap on the bottom of the screen ;)

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved guys. Actually it turns out the box was hovering because the width of the box is too big on the screen I guess. And after switching to a larger screen (5.4 inch, previously was 4 inch) on the graphical layout the box was right at the bottom. Thanks for the help :) well that was silly, sorry for the fuss, I'm new in android.

Comment: On smaller devices this won't be the solution. I think the solution for the box (imageview) being to big and scaled down and keeping the whitespaces is 'adjustViewBounds'. Developing for Android is keeping almost every device, screen size etc. in mind.

Comment: Ahh, now I see how that adjustViewBounds works it keeps the scale of the image fixed regardless of any screen size right? This will surely come in handy. Thanks brains.